Proving commutator of velocity differentiation and total time differentiation is position differentiation
Inside Qmechanic's answer to this question on Nielson form of Lagrange equations, he used that
$$[\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot q},\frac d {dt}]=\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$$
But after repetitive trying on convincing myself a proof of this result, I still failed to do so.
Can someone help me by providing a proof of this result?

Suppose $L$ is a function of $t$, $q$, and $\dot q$. (In Qmechanic's answer, it can depend on every derivative $q^{(n)}$, but the proof is the same.)
We have
$$
\frac d{dt}L(t,q,\dot q)=\frac \partial{\partial t}L(t,q,\dot q)+\dot q\frac\partial{\partial q} L(t,q,\dot q)+\ddot q\frac\partial{\partial \dot q}L(t,q,\dot q)
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q}\frac d{dt}L(t,q,\dot q)=\frac {\partial^2}{\partial t\partial \dot q}L(t,q,\dot q)+\frac{\partial}{\partial q} L(t,q,\dot q)+\dot q\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q\partial\dot q}L(t,q,\dot q)+\ddot q\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \dot q\partial \dot q}L(t,q,\dot q).$$
Similarly,
$$
\frac d{dt}\frac\partial{\partial \dot q}L(t,q,\dot q)=\frac {\partial^2}{\partial t\partial\dot q}L(t,q,\dot q)+\dot q\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q\partial\dot q} L(t,q,\dot q)+\ddot q\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \dot q\partial \dot q}L(t,q,\dot q)$$
Thus, subtracting them, we obtain
$$\bigg(\frac\partial{\partial \dot q}\frac d{dt}-\frac d{dt}\frac\partial{\partial \dot q}\bigg)L(t,q,\dot q)=\frac\partial{\partial q}L(t,q,\dot q),$$
i.e.,
$$\big[\frac\partial{\partial\dot q},\frac d{dt}\big]=\frac\partial{\partial q}.$$

Minor typos, great answer.
